# Content Deployer gives error message after installing SmartTarget

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

I have configured the Deployer (.NET Website) for SmartTarget. When I try to publish an Dynamic Component Template it gives me an error while deploying.

1. Region has been defined in a TBB, which is included in the CT
2. Add to Smarttarget TBB is also added to the CT.

The error is:

> 2012-06-14 15:39:53,296 DEBUG DeploymentHandler - Deploying tcd:pub[14]/componentmeta[1300].
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,296 DEBUG DeploymentHandler - Active thread transaction: tcm:0-1731-66560.
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,296 DEBUG DeploymentHandler - Handing references from: tcd:pub[14]/componentmeta[1300] to: 1 items
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,296 DEBUG DeploymentHandler - Total tracked references: 15
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,296 DEBUG HandlerFactory - Retrieving typeHandler for itemURI: tcd:pub[14]/componentmeta[1300]
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 DEBUG DeploymentHandler - Deploying tcd:pub[0]/pub[14].
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 DEBUG HandlerFactory - Retrieving typeHandler for itemURI: tcd:pub[0]/pub[14]
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 DEBUG MetaDataFactory - Creating MetaDataFile for type=ComponentPresentations from file C:\tridion\incoming\testRD\Zip\tcm_0-1731-66560.Content\component_presentations.xml
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 DEBUG SectionVisitor - Processing section ComponentPresentations
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 DEBUG ComponentPresentationDeploy - ComponentPresentationDeploy.processItem called
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 DEBUG TCDLEngine - Setting target language to none
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 DEBUG TransformProcessor - Transforming file C:\tridion\incoming\testRD\Zip\tcm_0-1731-66560.Content\ComponentPresentations\tcm_14-1299_tcm_14-1302-32 source encoding null
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 DEBUG TCDLTransformer - Transforming tcdl enabled content for language none
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 WARN  DeployPipelineExecutor - Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failure message: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils for transaction: tcm:0-1731-66560
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 DEBUG DeployPipelineExecutor - Failure in Phase: Deployment Processing Phase attempt: 1 for transaction: tcm:0-1731-66560
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Final attempt in Phase: Deployment Processing Phase failed for transaction: tcm:0-1731-66560
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Original stacktrace for transaction: tcm:0-1731-66560
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
>       at com.tridion.smarttarget.tcdl.TcdlRegionTagHandler.doEndTag(TcdlRegionTagHandler.java:44) ~[smarttarget_core.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.tcdl.TagDispatcher.endTag(TagDispatcher.java:358) ~[cd_tcdl.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLParser.parse(TCDLParser.java:156) ~[cd_tcdl.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLTransformer.nonRELTransform(TCDLTransformer.java:122) ~[cd_tcdl.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.tcdl.TCDLTransformer.process(TCDLTransformer.java:83) ~[cd_tcdl.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer.transform(TCDLTransformer.java:118) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.TCDLTransformer.transform(TCDLTransformer.java:89) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.TransformProcessor.transformItem(TransformProcessor.java:185) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationDeploy.processComponentPresentation(ComponentPresentationDeploy.java:123) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.modules.ComponentPresentationDeploy.processItem(ComponentPresentationDeploy.java:105) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.processSection(SectionVisitor.java:83) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.SectionVisitor.process(SectionVisitor.java:60) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.Processor.process(Processor.java:109) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.workers.ProcessorWorker.doWork(ProcessorWorker.java:74) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.ProcessingPhase.execute(ProcessingPhase.java:73) ~[cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.runMainExecutePhase(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:186) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.doExecute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:97) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.phases.DeployPipelineExecutor.execute(DeployPipelineExecutor.java:61) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.TransactionManager.handleDeployPackage(TransactionManager.java:80) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at com.tridion.deployer.queue.QueueLocationHandler$1.run(QueueLocationHandler.java:176) [cd_deployer.jar:na]
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_11]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_11]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_11]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_11]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_11]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.6.0_11]
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 INFO  TransactionPersistence - Removing deployment transaction information: tcm:0-1731-66560
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 ERROR DeployPipelineExecutor - Unable to start processing deployment package with transactionId: tcm:0-1731-66560
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 DEBUG DeployPipelineExecutor - Checking if transaction is completed: tcm:0-1731-66560 is true
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Transaction is completed: tcm:0-1731-66560
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 INFO  DeployPipelineExecutor - Finished executing deployment pipeline for: tcm:0-1731-66560 in 94 ms.
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,312 INFO  TransactionManager - Cleaning up Deployment package for transaction: tcm:0-1731-66560 and type: CONTENT
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,328 INFO  TransactionManager - Finished handling of Deployment package: tcm:0-1731-66560 with type: CONTENT
>   2012-06-14 15:39:53,328 DEBUG QueueLocationHandler - Removing exclusive lock on Deployment package: tcm:0-1731-66560 with type: CONTENT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
```

It looks like you haven't installed the third-party-lib files.